# Angular Material Radio Button Outer Circle not align

Tags: angular, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to add some radio button to my angular form. I went to the material.angular.io site and used their code. However, the radio buttons do not look right. There is an outer and inner circle next to each other. So, I went here and found someone else's code and copied/pasted and got the same issue. Here is the code

```
 <mat-radio-group formControlName="options">
                        <mat-radio-button value="1">Option 01</mat-radio-button>
                        <mat-radio-button  value="2">Option 02</mat-radio-button>
                      </mat-radio-group>
```

In my angular module.ts, I added the MatRadioModule. I am not sure why I am getting this strange error. Has  anyone here ever seen this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try to reproduce no stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/angular/vojoygoxqxx?file=app%2Fradio-overview-example.html

Comment: Did you forget to add style of Material in your project ?

Comment: Hi, From the website, I copied the style snippets to the component scss but that  did not fix it. Is there a Material css file that needs to be imported?

Answer (score 2):

You have to import built-in css style in styles.css.

eg.`@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';`

Here is the more details [Doc](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)